# Drop down content in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to show all the categories in the database in each line of a JTable i have done that. Now when i click on the each row of JTable i need to show the list of products under it (considered as child of the category) as a drop down not as a drop down list which closes automatically when focus is lost, but it should stay there until i click on minimize icon in the same row. It is just like expanding content. so i can expand all categories individually. The working is similar to JTree but i need it in JTable so that i can show more information on each row in a proper format. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need TreeTable functionality. I bet this [article](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have the table model add/remove the subcategory rows when the button on the category is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at NetBeans `Outline`. Here's an [example](http://netbeans.dzone.com/news/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-) that shows how it looks.